# How to forward error to client in koa stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipeline, koa

I can't figure out how to pipe stream errors to the client in a Koa app. I have:

```
try {
  const res = await request.request({...streamingRequestConfig});
  ctx.body = new Passthrough(); // node stream.Passthrough, per https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/response.md#stream
  pipeline(res.data, ctx.body, err => {
    ctx.body = {streamError: err}
  });

  // (1) This error appears in pipeline() error handler,
  // but client receives only a 500 with no parseable body
  // res.data.emit('error', new Error('Test stream error');

  // (2) This error is caught below and returned to client
  // in response body, parseable with Body.json()
  // throw new Error('Test request error');
} catch (err) {
  ctx.body = {requestError: err}
}
```

and in my client:

```
const res = await fetch(url);
try {
  const data = await res.json();
  const error = data.streamError || data.requestError;
  if (error) {
    // Error thrown from (2) is caught here
    displayErrorToUser(error);
  }
} catch (err) {
  // Error thrown from (1) is caught here, but not parseable;
  // it is a generic 500
  console.error('Parse error')
}
```

As described in the comments, throwing at (2) generates a response body with an error that can be parsed on the client, but a stream error (as emulated at (1)) responds with a generic 500: Internal Server Error.

How can I pass the stream error to the client so I can display + log it?

Comment: I think the error handler fires after the stream has already been piped to the response (`ctx.body`), but I'm not sure how to change that...

Comment: What error are you trying to handle? There's not much that can be done for the client if something fails mid stream. If they already have a 200 response and half a json object, the content length won't match and the request will fail. You can't replace the existing response with a new json error.

Comment: You can log locally in an error handler though

Answer (score 0):

Appears the answer is that once the stream is piped to the response, and bytes are flowing to the client, the partial streamed response is already on the client and can't spontaneously be switched over to a JSON error response.

It is possible to log a stream error on the server, but there's nothing more to do for the client in this case except catch an error in the `Body.json()` response parsing and note that the stream failed.